# Error when trying to start code server with new maven plugin for GWT

Tags: java, maven, gwt, maven-plugin

I'm trying to create a GWT project using the tbroyer maven plugin.

I followed the instructions from here
https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes/
but when I try to run the code serevr I get this:

```
[INFO] myproject .......................................... FAILURE [ 10.700 s]
[INFO] myproject-shared ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] myproject-client ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 35.076 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-21T17:59:01+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 20M/165M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6:codeserver (default-cli) on project myproject: GWT exited with status 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6:codeserver (default-cli) on project myproject: GWT exited with status 1
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:309)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:194)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:107)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:993)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:345)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: GWT exited with status 1
        at net.ltgt.gwt.maven.AbstractDevModeMojo.execute(AbstractDevModeMojo.java:254)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 20 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

*UPDATE*
Ok this must be the cause

```
C:\Users\user\work\gwt\myproject\myproject-client\target\classes\com\itt\myproject\App.gwt.xml (Access is denied) (net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-8:generate-module:default-generate-module:generate-resources)

org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: C:\Users\user\work\gwt\myproject\myproject-client\target\classes\com\itt\myproject\App.gwt.xml (Access is denied)
    at net.ltgt.gwt.maven.GenerateModuleMojo.execute(GenerateModuleMojo.java:231)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
```

Comment: "GWT exited with status 1" indicates GWT compiler errors. Check preceding messages.

Comment: Yes, if your operating system won't let your build tool _write a file to the target dir_, you may have a problem.

Comment: Rather use Linux than Windows with gwt dev mode, I had issues with Windows+gwt dev mode due to strict file locking under Windows.